# How do I get rid of micro lag?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, display, 23.04

I switched to Ubuntu recently and have noticed micro lag and low frame rate in some applications. I have 165Hz monitor, but Ubuntu feels laggy. I have recorded few videos in slow motion.

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19sVwecchlf1e9DbPyQcDSW9aOszAebs9/view?usp=drive_link)
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19pylNBzhOuwI5vACz44UtioDodtrDrfU/view?usp=sharing)
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19pOE6YlEWlU6ZGX-issbTQ1kFCdsIMJL/view?usp=sharing)
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18o3MPxdooELLspOM1Rv7ILdOuiHy7T4U/view?usp=sharing)

I hope the lags and micro stuttering are visible.

I have Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 Super GPU, my driver version is 535.104.05 and CUDA Version is 12.2, 16GB of RAM installed with i7-7700K CPU.

Ubuntu doesn't use more than 10% CPU and 20% GPU usually, but I have this lag and micro stuttering that hurts my eyes.

I use X11 as my window manager. I have tried Wayland but it was even more laggy

More detailed specs:

```
svitoslavpc                 
description: Desktop Computer
product: System Product Name (SKU)
vendor: System manufacturer
version: System Version
serial: System Serial Number
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-3.0.0 dmi-3.0.0 smp vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To be filled by O.E.M. sku=SKU uuid=1d0c7ac0-d7da-11dd-b4e8-107b444b3d0e
   *-firmware
   description: BIOS
   vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
   physical id: 0
   version: 1203
   date: 12/25/2017
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 16MiB
   capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: 45
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 16GiB
   *-bank:0
      description: [empty]
      physical id: 0
      slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
    *-bank:1
      description: [empty]
      physical id: 1
      slot: ChannelA-DIMM2
    *-bank:2
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
      product: BLS8G4D240FSE.16FBD2
      vendor: CRUCIAL
      physical id: 2
      serial: DB96C6A6
      slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
    *-bank:3
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
      product: BLS8G4D240FSE.16FBD2
      vendor: CRUCIAL
      physical id: 3
      serial: 44314910
      slot: ChannelB-DIMM2
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
*-cache:0
   description: L1 cache
   physical id: 4b
   slot: L1 Cache
   size: 256KiB
   capacity: 256KiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=1
*-cache:1
   description: L2 cache
   physical id: 4c
   slot: L2 Cache
   size: 1MiB
   capacity: 1MiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=2
*-cache:2
   description: L3 cache
   physical id: 4d
   slot: L3 Cache
   size: 8MiB
   capacity: 8MiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=3
*-cpu
   description: CPU
   product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
   vendor: Intel Corp.
   physical id: 4e
   bus info: cpu@0
   version: 6.158.9
   serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   slot: LGA1151
   size: 3966MHz
   capacity: 4200MHz
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 100MHz
   capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities cpufreq
   configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 microcode=244 threads=8
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:140 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
*-sata
   description: SATA controller
   product: 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 17
   bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
   logical name: scsi2
   logical name: scsi4
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
   configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
   resources: irq:127 memory:df248000-df249fff memory:df24c000-df24c0ff ioport:f050(size=8) ioport:f040(size=4) ioport:f020(size=32) memory:df24b000-df24b7ff
*-pnp00:00
   product: PnP device PNP0c02
   physical id: 0
   capabilities: pnp
   configuration: driver=system
*-pnp00:02
   product: PnP device PNP0c02
   physical id: 2
   capabilities: pnp
   configuration: driver=system
*-pnp00:03
   product: PnP device PNP0c02
   physical id: 3
   capabilities: pnp
   configuration: driver=system
*-pnp00:04
   product: PnP device PNP0b00
   physical id: 4
   capabilities: pnp
   configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
*-pnp00:06
   product: PnP device PNP0c02
   physical id: 6
   capabilities: pnp
   configuration: driver=system
*-pnp00:07
   product: PnP device PNP0c02
   physical id: 7
   capabilities: pnp
   configuration: driver=system
 *-pnp00:08
   product: PnP device PNP0c02
   physical id: 8
   capabilities: pnp
   configuration: driver=system
*-pnp00:09
   product: PnP device PNP0c02
   physical id: 9
   capabilities: pnp
   configuration: driver=system
*-memory UNCLAIMED
   description: Memory controller
   product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
   capabilities: bus_master
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:df244000-df247fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 00
   serial: 10:7b:44:4b:3d:0e
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=6.2.0-31-generic duplex=full firmware=0.2-4 ip=192.168.1.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:128 memory:df200000-df21ffff
*-power UNCLAIMED
   description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   physical id: 1
   version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   capacity: 32768mWh
*-graphics
   product: EFI VGA
   physical id: 2
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   capabilities: fb
   configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080
```

About page:

[image: About page screenshot]

neofetch:

[image: neofetch]

I want to make my Ubuntu feel smoother and get rid of the micro lag. Is there somewhat like triple buffering in Wayland?